# How can I capture all the queries that are being executed against a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ecommerce application that I believe is not properly caching all of our images and so I would like to capture all the queries that are occurring against our images table.

I need to be able to do this without installing anything or adding any code to the solution.

Can this be accomplished with SQL Profiler or another tool that does not require code modification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is indeed the right tool for this.

You can attach it to your database, set some filters (for example, the text should contain the table name) and what events to log and off you go.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Profiler will capture the queries as you have identified, you could also inspect the query cache, but it would not necessarily have all of the queries against that table still in cache, so should not be relied on.